# Como solucionar erro "TypeError: must be unicode, not str" no Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Ao efetuar backup do meu banco de dados em *Sqlite3*, o interpretador Python retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> TypeError: must be unicode, not str

na linha `f.write("%s\n" % linha)`, não consegui achar uma solução a respeito deste erro.

Segue o código:

```
#coding: utf-8
__author__ = 'Dener Carvalho'

import sqlite3
import io

#Conecta ao banco
conn = sqlite3.connect('clientes.db')

with io.open('clientes_dump.sql', 'w') as f:
    for linha in conn.iterdump():
        f.write("%s\n" % linha)

print 'Backup efetuado com sucesso.'
print 'Salvo como clientes_dump.sql'

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grave em [formato binário](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/io.html#binary-i-o) e não terá problemas. É temerário gravar um *backup* de um banco de dados como texto:

```
#coding: utf-8
__author__ = 'Dener Carvalho'

import sqlite3
import io

#Conecta ao banco
conn = sqlite3.connect('clientes.db')

with io.open('clientes_dump.sql', 'wb') as f:
    for linha in conn.iterdump():
        f.write("%s\n" % linha)

print 'Backup efetuado com sucesso.'
print 'Salvo como clientes_dump.sql'

conn.close()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/Unicode.py).

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou aqui. Eu não sei porque este erro aconteceu, pensei que como texto funcionava.

Comment: Estou tentatdo a votar -1 pro você nem comentar a o que o erro quer dizer - apesar da resposta estar boa, uma vez que o banco pode ter blobs.  Mas sugiro a leitura de http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)

Comment: @jsbueno a pergunta não fala sobre isto, ele só quer a solução, você mesmo reconhece que a resposta está boa, então um negativo seria pirraça, e qualquer informação adicional sobre isto não vai resolver nada, a solução é esta, qualquer uma que envolva Unicode potencialmente gerará problema. Olhe minhas respostas, quando é pertinente, eu explico, este não é o caso.

Answer (score 1):

No Python, `str` seria um tipo binário de dados, enquanto que `unicode` é algo mais elaborado. Você abriu o arquivo esperando receber `unicode` e está tentando escrever `str`, por isso o erro.

Há duas opções:

## 1. Abrir o arquivo em modo binário

```
with io.open('clientes_dump.sql', 'wb') as f: # mude para 'wb'
    for linha in conn.iterdump():
        f.write("%s\n" % linha)
```

## 2. Converter `str` para `unicode`

```
with io.open('clientes_dump.sql', 'w') as f:
    for linha in conn.iterdump():
        f.write("%s\n" % unicode(linha))
```

[Veja mais sobre `io` aqui](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.